# How to use condition in form action thymeleaf

Tags: forms, conditional-statements, thymeleaf, action, ternary

**i want to use ternary, for my action form in thymeleaf like this, is that possible?
i try this one, but doesn't work**

```
<form th:action=**"${action} == UH ? @{/summary/approvalDH} : ${action} == BOD ? @{/summary/approvalBOD} : @{/summary/approvalUH}"** name="myForm" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post" >
```

**but if there is one condition its work**

```
<form th:action=**"${action} == 'UH' ? @{/summary/approvalDH} : @{/summary/approvalUH}"** name="myForm" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post" >
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use parenthesis:

```
        th:action=**"${action} == UH ?  (${action} == BOD ?@{/summary/approvalBOD} : @{/summary/approvalUH}):@{/summary/approvalDH} "
```

Comment: What is that `=**` doing? Or, more precisely, what do the double stars mean?